# HTML5 audio what audio formats are supported

Tags: html, audio, formats

I have short sound that I wish to play in my webapp using HTML5.
I save it in 3 formats. wav, mp3 and ogg

I created 3  tags to play in different formats.

```
<audio controls autobuffer>
<source src="random_d5c589b1.wav" type="audio/x-wav">
</audio>

<audio controls autobuffer>
<source src="random_d5c589b1.ogg" type="application/ogg">
</audio>

<audio controls autobuffer>
<source src="random_d5c589b1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

IE9 shows that it can play mp3 and it plays

FF5 shows that it can play wav, ogg. I do not hear it.

Chrome 12 is able to play all 3 formats but I do not hear anything.

When I use different audio files I can hear them in FF and Chrome. But I can't hear those I need.

Here is example:- http://kvartira-n.com/test-site/sound2.html

---

Thanks to  Juhana. The problem was that I had only 2 channel speakers and 5+1 was selected in Windows. It is not clear to me why but some audio 2 channel files were hearable and other wasn't.

Thanks everyone problem is resolved now.

Comment: Interesting reading: http://24ways.org/2010/the-state-of-html5-audio

Comment: Works fine for me both in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Juhana!!! I found that I had 5.1 audio in systems and only 2 channel speakers.

Answer (score 1):

It's browser-specific.
e.g. The .ogg file works in chrome and firefox but doesn't work in safari.

It's a good idea to provide alternate audio files.
Here is the example by MDN web docs.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="random_d5c589b1.wav" type="audio/x-wav">
  <source src="random_d5c589b1.ogg" type="application/ogg">
  <source src="random_d5c589b1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```