# HTML5 Audio Object - which WAV formats are supported?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, encoding

I'm using the `Audio()` object in order to play some sound files in the browser.

```
var audio = new Audio(file);
audio.play()
```

The sound files can come from 2 different "places" and appear to have **slightly** differing formats.

The file plays correctly when the `wav` file being passed to the `Audio` object has the following properties (from "Get Info" on Mac)...

```
Sample rate: 8,000
Bits per sample: 16
Duration: 00:17
Audio Channels: 1
File size: 278KB
```

However, when a file has the properties below, I hear nothing, I don't see the little speaker icon in the tab and have no console errors, it's just like nothing happens.

```
Sample rate: 8,000
Duration: 00:29
Audio Channels: 1
File size: 31KB
```

**NOTE**: The only difference is that the second example doesn't have a "Bits per sample" value? ALSO, note the file sizes, despite the lengths???

Can anyone shed any light on this?

NB: This is not related to this issue...
[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762372/html5-audio-what-audio-formats-are-supported)

Comment: 29 seconds in 31 KB, that doesn’t right. Are you sure that WAV file is intact, can you play it using other programs?

Comment: @CBroe, yes if I open it in iTunes, it plays fine!

Answer (score 1):

Bits per sample is one of the most important factors that is needed to play audio.

More bits per sample gets you better precision, which leads to a more accurate representation of the source signal, which leads to better audio.

A higher value of bits per sample will lead to bigger File sizes.

The one with bits per sample would work without any hassle. You don't hear any sound with the one with no 'bits per sample', as you are not specifying what should the audio be like.

Some references which really help-

- [JSSoundRecorder](https://github.com/daaain/JSSoundRecorder)
- Custom Audio Effects in JavaScript with the [Web Audio API](http://noisehack.com/custom-audio-effects-javascript-web-audio-api/)
- Quantization, Sample Rate, and [Bits Per Sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/audiofool/archive/2006/08/16/703382.aspx)

Comment: Yeh thats some good background reading, but doesn't really address my specific question. Thanks though

Comment: The one with bits per sample would work without any hassle. You don't hear any sound with the one with no 'bits per sample', as you are not specifying what should the audio be like.

Comment: So how come it plays in iTunes, VLC, QuickTime etc? :-/

Comment: Not sure about that. Maybe they play it at default 'bits per sample' value.